# Some questions about php docker images and codeigniter

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I recently had some problems with creating containers for my CodeIgniter 4 application. My composer and Dockerfile were targeting the container's "/var/www" as the "volume" ('./' in relation to docker-compose .yml) and workdir. And I was never able to access my application on my host, I tried countless binds 8084, 9000, 8080, 8000, 8081 and I didn't understand why all the other containers worked (mariadb and adminer). And researching, I discovered that by directing the volume to "/var/www/html" and navigating to "http://localhost:[port]/public", Voilà! it works.

What's more, regarding my project itself, as it is a ci4, if I try to start it as recommended using "spark serve" arguments by adding CMD ["php", "spark", "serve"] in the Dockerfile and changing the volume and the working directory that Apache is directed to (e.g. change it to "/var/www), it still doesn't work, when I access the address on my host I get something like NS_CONNECTION_ERR_REFUSED. Can anyone tell me why it occurs or who Is it responsible for this? Could it be Apache? Do other images like FPM and Alpine also behave like this?

my actual Dockerfile and docker-compose:

```
FROM php:8.3.3-apache

ARG user
ARG uid

RUN a2enmod  rewrite

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    libicu-dev \
    libmariadb-dev \
    unzip zip \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev 

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install intl mysqli pdo pdo_mysql zip

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

WORKDIR /var/www/html

USER $user
```

|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

````
version: '3.1'

services:
  app:
    container_name: busquejobs_app
    build:
      args:
          user: gvaldivia
          uid: 1000
      context: ./
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - tt_default
  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: busquejobs_db
    restart: always
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./docker-compose/mysql:/var/lib/mysql 
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - tt_default
      
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    container_name: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - tt_default

networks:
  tt_default:```
````